# Gregex and forward/backward lookahead

Tags: regex, gtk

I am writing a language definition `.lang` for GTK GSourceView which uses [Gregexp](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-regex-syntax.html). Now I want to match ordinary numbers and ordinary numbers preceded by `#`, while I want to exclude any kind of letters or `_`.

For this group of strings:

```
001abc_
abc_001_abc
#abc_001
#001_abc
#001
#2
10
```

I tried a regular expression:

```
[#]?(?<![a-zA-Z_]+)([0-9])+(?![a-zA-Z_]+)
```

But I get two problems. Firstly `?<!` isn't supported and secondly I get matches even for first four strings. It looks like `+` in the subgroups `()` doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not use a quantifier `+` in a lookbehind `(?<![a-zA-Z_]+)`

If you only want to match the last 3, maybe you can match an optional `#` with one or more digits `\d+` between word boundaries `\b`:

[`\b#?\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/shzvDU/1)

Comment: Thank you for info about `+`. Your example fails to match `#001` and `#2`. What about `[#]?\b[0-9]+\b`? You gave me an idea. Maybee you meant it like this?

Comment: @71GA You you want to match this? [`((?<=#)(?=.*\d)[^\d]*(\d+)|\b#?\d+\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/shzvDU/2)

Comment: What I wrote works perfectly! So i will give you credits.

Comment: Happy to contribute solving your problem!